# ng-cookie and Theme Switcher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to add cookie in my controller that switch thems .
here is my code :

```
Common.css is my default css for every user
```

**HeaderCtrl.js**

```
myApp.controller('headerCtrl', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
    var currentTheme = $cookieStore.get("App/Common/Style/Common/common.css");

    $scope.changeTheme = function (theme) {
        if (!currentTheme) {
            $scope.currentTheme = "App/Common/Style/Common/common.css";
        }
        else if(theme === 'red'){
            $scope.currentTheme = "App/Common/Style/Switcher/styleRed.css";
        } else if (theme === 'common') {

            $scope.currentTheme = "App/Common/Style/Switcher/common.css";

        } 
        $cookieStore.put("App/Common/Style/Common/common.css", $scope.currentTheme);
    };


});
```

**HTML**

```
<link ng-href="{{currentTheme}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

***UPDATE***
that's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krimple/9dSb2/) i got idea from .

it change my themes, but cookie not working .
am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is that you accessing cookie first time when controller load but you are not assigning it to scope.

```
myApp.controller('headerCtrl', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {

    //assign to scope
    $scope.currentTheme = $cookieStore.get("App/Common/Style/Common/common.css");

    $scope.changeTheme = function (theme) {

        if(theme === 'red'){
            $scope.currentTheme = "App/Common/Style/Switcher/styleRed.css";
        } else if (theme === 'common') {

            $scope.currentTheme = "App/Common/Style/Switcher/common.css";

        } 
        $cookieStore.put("App/Common/Style/Common/common.css", $scope.currentTheme);
    };

});
```

that is the reason when page load it don't work for binding `{{currentTheme }}` but when you invoke `changeTheme()` it starts working.

Comment: thx a lot but now i get this error : Error: currentTheme is not defined     and what i did is replace $scope.currentTheme instead of var

Comment: you need to remove check of `if (!currentTheme) {`